# Script executes on page load, should only execute on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple file upload page with messages that show at the bottom at intervals, so I used setInterval for the delay.

The following function is supposed to start only after the "Upload" button is clicked, but it starts executing as soon as the page is loaded (this is not the project's landing page).

How can I write this so that it does not start executing on page load but instead is executed only when the Upload button is clicked?

Here is the entire html code including the script:

My research hasn't come up with anything directly relevant to the issue of executing on page load versus on a button click.  I have found the opposite (wants it to execute on page load, not button click) but not this.  I don't want it to execute on page load at all, only on button click.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
var counter = 0;

function myTimer() {
  counter++;
  var t = counter;
  document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = t;
  if (counter >= 4) {
    console.log("REACHED THE END!!");
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_upload" style="margin-left: 14%">File Upload</div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 6%;">
  <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn">Select file</button>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 10%;">
  <button class="btn" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="myTimer()">Upload</button></div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 6%;">
  <div id="td1" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 1</div>
  <div id="td2" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 2</div>
  <div id="td3" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 3</div>
  <div id="td4" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 4</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div id="td7" class="text_display" style="color:rgb(175,222,162); font-size: 13pt; margin-left: 8%;">Finished</div>
<br>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: All you need to do is wrap the `setInterval` call in a click event handler. If you searched and found lots of examples of people with button click events that they wanted to turn into page load events, why didn't you look at how they were doing the button click events?

Comment: connexo, the link you provided doesn't address the issue.  I still need to keep the script from executing on page load.  addEventListener may hold a clue, but it's not clear from the document you linked to.

Comment: `document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("click",function() setInterval(myTimer, 1000); })`  - however when you submit a form the script is cleared

Comment: mplungjan, that looks useful but how do I get the timer to stop after it reaches four?  And do I keep the code that sets var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);?  If I delete that, dev console says myTimer is not defined; if I keep it, the script starts executing on page load.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an event listener to the button:

```js
var myVar, counter; // global vars

document.getElementById("submit_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  counter = 0;
  myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
});

function myTimer() {
  counter++;
  var t = counter;
  document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = t;
  if (counter >= 4) {
    console.log("REACHED THE END!!");
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header_upload" style="margin-left: 14%">File Upload</div>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 6%;">
  <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn">Select file</button>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" />
  </div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 10%;">
  <button class="btn" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="myTimer()">Upload</button></div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div class="upload_text" style="margin-left: 6%;">
  <div id="td1" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 1</div>
  <div id="td2" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 2</div>
  <div id="td3" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 3</div>
  <div id="td4" class="text_display">*&nbsp;Step 4</div>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<div id="td7" class="text_display" style="color:rgb(175,222,162); font-size: 13pt; margin-left: 8%;">Finished</div>
<br>
```

Comment: mplungjan, thanks very much for taking the time to do this.  I will implement this now and update with my results.

Comment: mplungjan -- yes, that works.  For anyone who has the same trouble with setInterval (which has its problems), this post will be very helpful.  Thanks very much again.

Comment: If you had a form, you should add the listener to the form's submit handler